# Rotating image in python (cv2) won't center

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to rotate a image in python using cv2. I have so far just copied examples from the net, but can't get them to work as intended. My code is as follows:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
center = (w / 2, h / 2)

M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, 270, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (h, w))
cv2.imshow("rotated", rotated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

original image:
[image]
and my results:

[image: results]
I'm using python3.7 through Thonny.

**EDIT and ANSWER:**

Thanks to @jeru-luke for pointing me in the right direction. Code below modified from [this post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/) by Adrian Rosebrock.

```
import cv2
import imutils

image = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

rotated = imutils.rotate_bound(image, 90)
cv2.imshow("Rotated (Correct)", rotated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Without posting the original image, it is impossible to ascertain what rotation you should be expecting. Additionally, it should be, `rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h))`

Comment: In addition to the previous comment have alook at [THIS POST](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/) on how to correctly rotate images.

Comment: @RickM. original photo up now, sorry. :)

Comment: @wigeon I guess from the previous comments, you should be able to solve your issue.

Comment: @RickM. Indeed! Thanks to both! Updated the original post with the solution now.